# scope.watch to fire whenever the value is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I noticed scope.watch fires only if the value is changed. Right now in order to fire scope.watch everytime I am doing it like this:

```
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);

module.controller("TreeCtrl", function($scope) {


    $scope.changeValue = function(){
        $scope.name = new Date();
    };

});

module.directive("tree", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template:'<div>sample</div>',
        link : function(scope, elm, $attrs) {
           scope.$watch('name', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                        console.log(scope.userName);            
                    });  
        }
    };
});
```

i.e $scope.name = new Date();

Is there any other way to capture scope.watch whenever the variable is set.

My fidddle is http://jsfiddle.net/xxkgxLr9/34/

Is scope.watch the correct way to do that?

My goal is to fire a piece of code in directive from controller every time when a scope variable is set

Answer (score 2):

```
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);

module.controller("TreeCtrl", function($scope) {


    $scope.changeValue = function(){
        $scope.name = new Date();
        console.log($scope.name);
    };

});

module.directive("tree", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template:'<div>sample</div>',

        link : function($scope, elm, $attrs) {
           $scope.$watch('userName', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                        console.log($scope.userName);    
                console.log($scope.name);
                    });  
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you share what is the difference between the code what you shared and what I posted in my question?

Comment: Seems you just changed "scope" to "$scope", I am sorry that will not do any magic.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Anvesh2727/xxkgxLr9/39/

When a scope value is changed it triggers the $scop.$watch and prints new scope value and current date in console

Answer (score 2):

Scope for the button and directive element is different. Your code needs some modification. $compile should not be given as param to the directive function.

data in controller is passed to directive using scope:{'name': '@'}

```
     `http://jsfiddle.net/bandhavya/xxkgxLr9/35/`
```

Here watch gets fired whenever the variable name is changed.

Comment: #Raghav Let me know whether this solution helped you or not

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to set variable only via setter function you can try this:

```
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);

module.controller("TreeCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.changeValue = function(){
        $scope.updateName(new Date());
    };

});

module.directive("tree", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template:'<div>sample</div>',
        link : function(scope, elm, $attrs) {
           scope.updateName = function (newVal) {
               console.log(newVal);
           };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: By doing this way directive/controller are becoming tightly coupled. Controller should not know then methods residing inside directives.